# Solution of spoj with code AP2 seems to be correct but returns COMPILATION ERROR on online judge but works fine on code blocks

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    long long int t,i,term3,lastterm3,sum,n,d,a,j;
    scanf("%lld",&t);
    for(i=1;i<=t;i++){
        scanf("%lld %lld %lld",&term3,&lastterm3,&sum);
        n = ((2*sum)/(term3+lastterm3));
        printf("%lld\n",n);
        d = ((lastterm3-term3)/(n-5));
        a = (term3-(2*d));
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
            printf("%lld ",(a+(j-1)*d));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this is my solution of problem AP2 of SPOJ. This seems to work correctly on code blocks but returns compilation error on SPOJ

Comment: And the error would be what exactly? Don't go the doctor and just say *ouch!*

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess, you are using the compiler (online judge?) in C90 mode, which has no support for the `long long` type, along with the `%lld` printf formats.

Try setting your compiler to C99 or later. Or use a C99 compiler.

This program is otherwise a valid C99 program, albeit a bit shoddy: not testing the return values from `scanf` *will* bite you.